# AWS Lambda function that serves files from S3 based on request

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have the following code

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    bucket = 'bucketName'
    prefix = 'folder1/'
    request = "requestURL"

    return s3.Object(bucket, prefix + request).get()['Body'].read()
```

I intend to use this with API Gateway to have a URL that I can query and serve a file from S3 like this:

function url: http://magic-lambda-function.aws....com/magic this is the URL that API Gateway provides.

If I would call http://magic-lambda-function.aws....com/magic/folder1/folder2/file1 ,read the file1 from s3_bucket/folder1/folder2/file1 and output it.

Has anyone tried something similar? Thank you in advance for any help.

PS: I can't serve the files directly from S3 because their names contain queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a Lambda function to do this, you can use AWS API Gateway and set up a service proxy - much simpler. AWS has built this functionality for you already (almost).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html